# IF w/ VLOOKUP until last row

Tags: vba, if-statement, foreach, vlookup

My goal with this script is to search a cell from the worksheet "BonDeCommande" (A column) on another worksheet called "BonDeReception" (also A column) using the formula VLOOKUP.

If it finds a corresponding value on the table array, it has to write "Oui" at J column on the same row of the lookup_value (A column on "BonDeCommande").

Script:

```
Sub Macro1()


Dim Search As Variant

Dim i As Range
Dim j As Range

LastRow = Worksheets("BC").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastR = Worksheets("BR").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
For Each i In Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    For Each j In Range("A2:A" & LastR)
    Range("J2").Select
    Search = Application.VLookup(BC.Range("A2:A" & "i"), BR.Range("A2:A" & "j"), 1, False)


    If Search = "A" & "i" Then
       Result = "OUI"

    Else
        Result = "NON"
        Range("J" & "i").Value = Result
    
    End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

However, the code doesn't work and I get a Runtime Error 424 message that highlights this line:

```
Search = Application.VLookup(BC.Range("A2:A" & "i"), BR.Range("A2:A" & "j"), 1, False)
```

Could you please enlighten me on what I've done wrong on my code? Or if is there an easier way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But also `i` and `j` are ranges and you are expecting them to be numbers.

Comment: So, do I have to change it to Variant instead? I did it and I received the same error message. Also tried As Integer but For Each control variable must be Variant or Object

Comment: You need to decide if you are looking for a number or a range and then be consistent in it's use.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating ranges as numbers also the second loop is not needed:

```
Sub Macro1()


    Dim Search As Variant
    
    Dim i As Range
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Worksheets("BonDeCommande").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
        
    For Each i In Worksheets("BonDeCommande").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        Search = Application.VLookup(i.Value, Worksheets("BonDeReception").Range("A:A"), 1, False)
        If Not IsError(Search) Then
            Result = "OUI"
        Else
            Result = "NON"
        End If
        i.Offset(,9).Value = Result
    Next i

End Sub
```

But this can all be done with a formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,BonDeReception!A:A,0)),"OUI","NON")
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you, you really saved my life haha